# mask some bits in a vector based on a different vector

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a vector `data[255:0]`. And another vector `len[3:0]` (`len` can only take a max value of 8 by definition). I need to do this (pseudo code):

```
bits = len*32;
data_mod[255:0] = {data[255:(255-(bits-1))], (256-bits)'0}
ex : if len = 6, then
data_mod[255:0] = {data[255:64], 64'b0}
```

Basically, grab only upper "len*32" bits from the original vector and zero out the rest.

I am stuck trying to do this in synthesizable SystemVerilog. Any ideas?

Comment: first of all you range should be [511:0] since len  is 4 bits wide. for the rest, shift right by 512 - len * 32 to grab upper bits. you can shift then left for the same amount to clean lower bits. Or you can play with  masks.

Comment: 256 bits is enough since max value of Len in the design is 8. I did think of right shift then left shift but am thinking there has to be a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with masks which might work in your case:

```
module bb;
   reg [255:0] data;
   reg [255:0] data_mod;
   reg [255:0] mask;
   reg [3:0]   len;

   initial begin
      len = 2;
      mask = {256{1'b1}} << (len * 32);
      data_mod = data & mask;
      $display("%0x", data_mod);
   end

endmodule // bb
```

and the result is

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0000000000000000
```